# In Mango, is it possible to reference background agents in class libraries?

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio-playback-agent, background-agent

I have an app which currently plays music (in the background) all the time it is running.
We wish to upgrade this in the Mango version of the app to use an Audio Playback Agent.

The majority of the playback logic is currently in a class library referenced by the main app. When using the, Beta 2 version of the, mango tools to add a reference to the agent from the class library project I get "Unable to add the selected reference because it is not supported by background agents."

Is this a known issue/by design?
Any known work arounds if it is?
Any alternatives? (Other than moving the code into the application project)

Yes, I've updated the library project to 7.1.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what references the library has.  Not all references are supported. You may need to change it.  Is the library a 7.1 library or a 7.0 library (which may be the issue).

Comment: The team also said that it would depend on the other references of the library but I found this to not be the case. That's actually the right behaviour and enforced by the tools. An agent should only ever be referenced by an app. You can run into all sorts of problems if trying to work a different way. Having spent the last week working with background audio agents I'm almost completely confident in how best to work with them and am plannign a write up.